# Ruby wrap dates in string with quotes

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

I have a string from file that looks like this:

```
"[[5473, 992, 'smth', Tue, 25 Mar 2014 05:08:12 UTC +00:00, Fri, 07 Mar 2014 22:55:42 UTC +00:00], [5473, 993, 'smth', Tue, 25 Mar 2014 14:38:05 UTC +00:00, Fri, 07 Mar 2014 22:57:33 UTC +00:00], [6084, 994, 'smth', Mon, 24 Mar 2014 23:37:37 UTC +00:00, Mon, 24 Mar 2014 23:37:37 UTC +00:00], [6084, 995, 'smth', nil, nil], [6084, 996, 'smth', nil, nil], [6084, 997, 'smth', nil, nil], [6084, 998, 'smth', nil, nil]]"
```

To correctly eval it as an array I need to wrap dates with quotes, I have created a regexp for cases when date is in the middle of an array:

```
(\s)\w{3},\s\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\+00:00(,)
```

and when date ends with `]` symbol:

```
(\s)\w{3},\s\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\+00:00(])
```

now I want to replace `\1` to `" '"` and `\2` to `"',"` or `"']"` correspondingly, with what ruby method I can accomplish my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two regex has only one difference, the last character is `,` or `]`. So joined them in character class using `[,\]]`. And use it in your ruby `gsub()` like this way:

```
input = input.gsub(/(\s)(\w{3},\s\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\+00:00)([,\]])/, " '\\2'\\3")
```

I have captured your date into group two `\\2` and captured `,` or `]` in group three `\\3`.

Capturing the group 1 wasn't necessary, but I didn't remove it. If you remove the capturing, then the grouping will be shifted from `\\2` to `\\1` and `\\3` to `\\2` in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert the dates to `Date` objects?

**Code**

```
require 'date'

regex = /\s(\w{3},\s\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\+00:00)/
s = str.gsub(regex, " Date.parse('\\1')")
```

and then

```
arr = eval(s)
```

to create an array from the string `s`.  Notice that the regex ends with `'00:00'`.

**Demo**

```
str = "[[5473, 992, 'smth', Tue, 25 Mar 2014 05:08:12 UTC +00:00, Fri, 07 Mar 2014 22:55:42 UTC +00:00],
  [5473, 993, 'smth', Tue, 25 Mar 2014 14:38:05 UTC +00:00, Fri, 07 Mar 2014 22:57:33 UTC +00:00],
  [6084, 994, 'smth', Mon, 24 Mar 2014 23:37:37 UTC +00:00, Mon, 24 Mar 2014 23:37:37 UTC +00:00],
  [6084, 995, 'smth', nil, nil],
  [6084, 996, 'smth', nil, nil],
  [6084, 997, 'smth', nil, nil],
  [6084, 998, 'smth', nil, nil]]"

require 'awesome_print'
ap eval(str.gsub(regex, " Date.parse('\\1')"))
[
    [0] [
        [0] 5473,
        [1] 992,
        [2] "smth",
        [3] #<Date: 2014-03-25 ((2456742j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
        [4] #<Date: 2014-03-07 ((2456724j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] 5473,
        [1] 993,
        [2] "smth",
        [3] #<Date: 2014-03-25 ((2456742j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
        [4] #<Date: 2014-03-07 ((2456724j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] 6084,
        [1] 994,
        [2] "smth",
        [3] #<Date: 2014-03-24 ((2456741j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
        [4] #<Date: 2014-03-24 ((2456741j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
    ],
    [3] [
        [0] 6084,
        [1] 995,
        [2] "smth",
        [3] nil,
        [4] nil
    ],
    [4] [
        [0] 6084,
        [1] 996,
        [2] "smth",
        [3] nil,
        [4] nil
    ],
    [5] [
        [0] 6084,
        [1] 997,
        [2] "smth",
        [3] nil,
        [4] nil
    ],
    [6] [
        [0] 6084,
        [1] 998,
        [2] "smth",
        [3] nil,
        [4] nil
    ]
]
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but I don't need Date objects, because this data is going to csv file, anyway +1 to you